# best MySQL primary key and table creation

Tags: mysql

What is the ideal primary key in MySQL?

I usually see `int` but:

```
int unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
```

Is `unsigned` necessary? I will only have a few thousand rows.

Is this default table creation right?

```
CREATE TABLE 'whatever' 
    'id' int unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
) DEFAULT CHARACTER SET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci ENGINE=InnoDB ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC
```

Answer (score 2):

The "ideal" primary key will satisfy several important properties:

unique - no two (or more) rows have the same value

simple - single column with simple native datatype

immutable - once assigned will never be changed

anonymous - conveys no meaningful information (for security, and helps with immutable property by giving steward less reason to change)

short - typically integer (numeric) type vs a longer string subject to characterset and collation

---

`INT UNSIGNED` is fine as a datatype; That's 32-bits, but the range of values at the upper end is larger than signed `INT`. So that's mismatch with 32-bit signed integer in the client e.g. Java primitive `int`, so we'd want to map 64-bit signed integer in the client e.g. Java primitive `long`.

We would also be good with `INT` (omit the `UNSIGNED`), and then we can map to 32-bit signed integer in the client.

For larger range of values, we can go `BIGINT`. I'd definitely omit the `UNSIGNED`, so we can map to client 64-bit signed integer e.g. Java `long` without invoking BigInteger class.

---

NOTE: The desirable properties for primary keys are not strict requirements; software projects can be successful using natural keys, composite keys, without invoking surrogate "id" column to server as primary key.